# Suggested Edit has incorrect Diff

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, diff

I suggested a change to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927016/1438599) early this morning but when I looked at the diff (after being told it was rejected) my small change appeared to be much more drastic.

I wanted to change the line

`and the output will be`

to

`and the output will be similar to`

but the diff came out [adding an entire line instead](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/282118) in the suggested edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP had made an edit to their post which was **not** reflected in your edit.

So it made it seem as if you were changing what the OP already changed back to the original.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even see the line I supposedly was adding in the answer's diff. It doesn't seem to have been there. That's why I am confused